# How to read logs and device info on users' android device?

Tags: java, android, logging, device

The scenario is (should happen to every app): Someone installed your apk and but sometimes the app crashed. You want the user to send back the logs and device info (vendor, model, os, sdk etc). You have such an menu item "report bug".

Is there such an example to implement it (in Java)? Thanks.

Comment: when I do search, most of the results are talking about logcat/adb/IDE etc.

Comment: You can use [Fabric](https://fabric.io/home) and setup crashlytics to your app this will send report on every crash with logs

Comment: @Leon I think he is talking about once the app is launched on playstore

Comment: You can use ACRA library to fetch all crashes from your app. Please see the link https://github.com/ACRA/acralyzer/wiki/setup#all-other-couchdb-versions

Comment: @Saikat1529   looks this is a service. This is useful too, but the original question is for client.

Answer (score 0):

> java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler

1. new a class implements UncaughtExceptionHandler
2. in your application set this UncaughtExceptionHandler (eg. onCreate()  Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(UncaughtExceptionHandlereh))
3. you can do your work in method uncaughtException(final Thread thread, final Throwable ex)